# calcular duração entre 2 valores dentro do input

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Olá, eu tenho um código em javascript que me ajuda a calcular a duração entre uma hora e outra, preciso saber como fazer para deixar esses valores mais dinâmicos, quero colocar a hora de entrada em um input, a hora de saida em outro input e o resultado (qtd de horas) em um 3º input.
Alguem pode me ajudar?

Segue o código que eu tenho

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var start = '21:00';
        var end = '22:20';

        s = start.split(':');
        e = end.split(':');

        min = e[1]-s[1];
        hour_carry = 0;
        if(min < 0){
                min += 60;
                hour_carry += 1;
        }
        hour = e[0]-s[0]-hour_carry;
        diff = hour + ":" + min;

        alert(diff);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom a parte mais difícil você já fez(não conferi o cálculo), então fica assim:

```html
 <input id="start" type="time" name="s_time"> : Start<br/>
 <input id="end" type="time" name="e_time"> : End<br/>
 <input type="button" value="Run" onclick="calcTime()" /><br/>
 <input id="result" type="text" value=""/> : Resultado
 <script>
  function calcTime()
 { var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
  s = start.split(':');
    e = end.split(':');
    min = e[1]-s[1];
    if(min < 10)
    {
     min = "0" + min;
    }
    hour_carry = 0;
    if(min < 0)
    { min += 60;
        hour_carry += 1;
    }
    hour = e[0]-s[0]-hour_carry;
    diff = hour + ":" + min;
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    result.value = diff;
 }
 </script>
```